# Exporting to Excel using Excel Link

Tags: excel, excellink

I often export results from Mathematica to Excel.  Then I have an auxiliary xlsm that formats the export file for me.  Would Excel Link allow me to export data to Excel and to format it?  The formatting I'm looking for would include column widths, borders, shading, numeric formats, and maybe something I'm not thinking about at the moment.

Added after Szabolcs' question:  An xlsm is an Excel file with macros in it.  Excel macros are VBA code with methods and properties specific to Excel worksheets.  They allow you to automate Excel.  All of the formatting that I'm referring to in the previous paragraph can be done with these macros. The macros in one Excel file can, and in this case do, work on the data in another Excel file.

Comment: What is an "xlsm"?